# Comparative and superlative of perfect?

Tags: word-usage

I have seen people saying it is a bad use of grammar when someone says 'more perfect' or 'most perfect', since something that is perfect can't be better if you look at it literally.

However, we do use it in our daily communication or when we want to express ourselves in a more romantic way, be it because you are writing poetry or for some other reason.

In my case, I'm translating a text from German in which the word *volkommener* appears midway, and this word itself translates to "more perfect" or "more complete". As I am wishing to translate it literally, as "more perfect", I came across this doubt, should I write "more perfect", or "perfecter", ignoring the fact that, if something is already perfect, there's no room for improvement whatsoever.

Comment: In this particular instance, we'd (1) need to see the whole (translated) sentence and (2) need to know what strictures apply (are you translating a scientific article, a pot-boiler ...?) to be able to suggest level of acceptability.